# linux + iptables + /etc/sysconfig/iptables

Tags: linux, rhel, iptables, firewall

on my linux machine I see the following:

```
 iptables -L
 Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
 target     prot opt source               destination

 Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
 target     prot opt source               destination

 Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
 target     prot opt source               destination
```

but from /etc/sysconfig/iptables I see many rules

so my question is

if from   iptables -L I see all are ACCEPT
dose this mean the /etc/sysconfig/iptables rules are not relevant ?

Comment: They're abviously now applied, and such you may say that they are not relevant in understanding what actually happens on the machine, but they might be relevant in what you want to happen.

Comment: classic typo there? "now" should be "not" ... Sometimes that one character can make so much difference :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` are loaded when the `iptables` service is started.

Since your firewall chains appear empty, there's probably nothing in there.  Do not that there could rules set like the `nat` and `raw` tables.

If you change the rules directly in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`, you need to restart the `iptables` service and inversely if you add rules dynamically with `iptables`, you may wish to save them with `iptables-save`.

Comment: so if I understanding the rules in the  /etc/sysconfig/iptables can affect the the traffic(block network etc )  and they are affected since iptable service is up - am I correct

Comment: if I want to ignore all the  rules ( to accept all ) - the simple way is to do -  /etc/sysconfig/iptables stop ?

Comment: The exact command depends on your OS but may well be `service iptables stop` or `systemctl stop iptables`.